Compressing multiple streams into a single archive file in .Net
Specifically, I'm talking about opening and writing multiple files into the same archive file over a long duration of time. This isn't about performance gains, it's about avoiding writing very large files to disk as an intermediary step then archiving them when the recording process ends (4-6 hours).
I am aware that the built-in compression classes don't allow opening multiple entries as streams at the same time, my question is if there is an alternative that does support this scenario.

I am not aware of an archive format that can scatter portions of an entry across the archive, which is what you would need for what you describe. They all have each entry contiguous in the archive. You'd need to define your own archive format to facilitate this.

That is an interesting point I've never even considered. In the end I used a LiteDB database to store my files and encrypt them (the end goal of this exercise). This lets me stream multiple files in at the same time with no issues!
